# Illuminate a rotating sphere from a specific point in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I've started working on an app and the basic idea is to to display a sphere which the user can rotate. I had no problems importing the .dae file of my sphere.
When I add a lighting of any sort(omni, area, directional etc.) in the scene graph, after running my app, the light only illuminates one specific part of the sphere and rotates with the sphere. 
I want to be able to rotate my sphere and have the light stay at a specific place such that I have a similar effect to the sun and earth. Only the area which is showing towards the sun/light should be illuminated when the sphere is rotating.

[image]

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/untitled")!

    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z: 100)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
```

Comment: Are you using `SceneKit` for this? I was about to add that tag but you really didn't say that. (If you are, maybe you should add it yourself? Personally, I think one should *not* add 5 tags where 2 would do, but in this case [iOS] and [swift] really don't hit those that focus on the actual Framework involved. And if you didn't know this, SceneKit is Apple's 3d graphics framework and probably will do what you want.

Comment: Good point, yes I'm using SceneKit.

Comment: Are you just using the default camera controls? In which case you’re rotating the entire scene not just the sphere.

Comment: What do you mean by default camera controls? I included the code I have written so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate a SCNSphere using a pan gesture recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851641/how-to-rotate-a-scnsphere-using-a-pan-gesture-recognizer)

Comment: `sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true` creates a camera that you can move around the scene. Instead you will want to use a gesture recogniser to rotate the sphere node itself.

Comment: @JamesP I'm actually not having troubles rotating the sphere, but rather with separating the light source from my sphere, such that the light doesn't rotate with the sphere.

Comment: I came across " sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true ", which mainly does the job, but does anybody know how to make the light come from an other angle than from the user's view?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably adding the light node as child node of the sphere, so when the sphere rotates the light rotates with it. 
Try adding the light to parent node of the sphere so the light will stay on the same position, because you will be rotating only with the sphere, not with the light.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. My Sphere has no parent node, I tried to create a parent node and add the sphere as a child Node, but I can't add a SCNScene (which my sphere is) as a child to a Parent Node (Cannot convert value of type 'SCNScene' to expected argument type 'SCNNode')

Comment: You can take your node from the scene to let constant and then add it to parent node.
Take it to let constant like this: ``` let mySphere = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/sceneName.scn")?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "sphere", recursively: false)```
And then you can add it to parent node like this: ```parentNode.addChildNode(mySphere)```
And then you will add your light to the same parent node.